# Component doesn't load while the route changes

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I want to create a nested route with its children's route.

Basically what I want is,

`https://localhost/contact` render the `ContactList` component.

`https://localhost/contact/add` render the `ContactAdd` component.

What I have tried is:

```js
let Layout = {
  template: '<div>Layout Page <router-view></router-view></div>'
};
let Home = {
  template: '<div>this is the home page. Go to <router-link to="/contact">contact</router-link> </div>'
};

let ContactList = {
  template: '<div>this is contact list, click <router-link to="/contact/add">here</router-link> here to add contact</div>'
};

let ContactAdd = {
  template: '<div>Contact Add</div>'
}

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'home',
    component: Layout,
    children: [{
        path: 'home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactList,
        children: [{
          path: 'add',
          component: ContactAdd
        }]
      },
    ]
  }]
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'App': {
      template: '<div><router-view></router-view></div>'
    },
  },
  router
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<section id="app">
  <app></app>
</section>
```

Here, the problem is when I change the route from `/client` to `/client/add`, the view doesn't render. What is the problem with the nested children's route here? How to solve this issue?

I check this documentation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html, but It didn't help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one `<router-view>` in the template of `<ContactList>` to load its children route.

Or if you'd like to display `ContactAdd` in `Layout`, moves `ContactAdd` to direct child of path=`/`.

```js
let Layout = {
  template: '<div>Layout Page <router-view></router-view></div>'
};
let Home = {
  template: '<div>this is the home page. Go to <router-link to="/contact">contact</router-link> </div>'
};

let ContactList = {
  // add <router-view> in order to load children route of path='/contact'
  template: '<div>this is contact list, click <router-link to="/contact/add">Add Contact In sub Router-View</router-link> here to add contact<p><router-view></router-view></p> Or Click <router-link to="/addcontact">Add Contact In Current Router-View</router-link></div>'
};

let ContactAdd = {
  template: '<div>Contact Add</div>'
}

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'home',
    component: Layout,
    children: [{
        path: 'home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactList,
        children: [{
          path: 'add',
          component: ContactAdd
        }]
      },
      {
        path: 'addcontact', // or move ContactAdd as direct child route of path=`/`
        component: ContactAdd,
      }
    ]
  }]
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'App': {
      template: '<div><router-view></router-view></div>'
    },
  },
  router
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<section id="app">
  <app></app>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there any pros and cons of using both type of routing?

Comment: it is a choice where shows the `ConactAdd`, it is not related to any pros and cons.